# Change specific lines in a word file with Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word

I am using Apache POI lib in order to change automatically word files. I want to create a software which will have as an input some text, and put it in specific lines of the word file. How is it possible to have access in specific lines fo a word file? I mean how is it possible to create "variable areas" inside a word file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bookmarks inside Word documents using Microsoft Word. I have done it one week ago. I inserted bookmarks in the document by selecting the text that will be replaced then insert -> bookmark and type a new bookmark name. After that in your code you should implement something like this in your util classes :

Original code found here : http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Replacing-the-value-of-the-bookmarks-td5710052.html